# To find if the input given is lucky or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

My aim: Two inputs will be given.
purchase date and number on plate.
My code should add all numbers of purchase date till single digit is reached and compare it with the similar addition of plate number.
If the both the numbers turn out to be same , it should return lucky otherwise it should display dare.
This is what I tried:

```
def lucky_dare():
    input1=input("enter ; ")
    input2=input("enter:")

    s=str(input1)
    p1=int(s[0])
    p2=int(s[1])
    p3=int(s[2])
    sty=[]
    ma=max([p1,p2,p3])
    while ma>0:
        if p1>0 and p2>0 and p3>0:
            sty.append(input1)




        elif p1<1 and p2<0 and p3>0:
            sty.append(int(s[2]))


        elif p1<1 and p2>0 and p3<1:
            sty.append(int(s[1]+"0"))

        elif p1<1 and p2>0 and p3>0:
            sty.append(int(s[1]+s[2]))


        elif p1>0 and p2<1 and p3<1:
            sty.append(int(s[0]+"0"+"0"))

        elif p1>0 and p2<1 and p3>0:
            sty.append(int(s[0]+"0"+s[2]))


        elif p1>0 and p2>0 and p3<1:
            sty.append(int(s[0]+s[1]+"0"))
        else:
            pass
        p1-=1
        p2-=1
        p3-=1
        ma-=1
    print(sum(sty))
lucky_dare()
```

But I am getting several errors. So I couldn't display what errors I got here. Where am I going wrong? Can someone please help. Thanks in advance for your time and help:)

Comment: either your question is incomplete or your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nicer, simpler and cleaner way to solve your problem:

```
import re
def recursive_sum(text):
    while (len(text) > 1):
        numbers = re.findall(r'\d', text)
        _sum = sum(map(int, numbers))
        text = str(_sum)
    return text


def luck_dare():
    input1= input("enter ; ")
    input2=input("enter:")
    return recursive_sum(input1) == recursive_sum(input2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your code, but it can be done much simpler. Here is my attempt, but it can still be optimized:

```
def lucky_dare():
    dop = sum([int(i) for i in input("enter date of purchase: ").split('/')])
    # 23/05/1998
    while dop > 9:
        dop = sum([int(i) for i in str(dop)])

    pn = int(input("enter plate number: "))  # 2345
    while pn > 9:
        pn = sum([int(i) for i in str(pn)])

    print('lucky' if dop == pn else 'dare')
    # print(dop, pn)


lucky_dare()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lucky_dare():
    input1=input("enter date: ")
    input2=input("enter car number:")

    # Evaluating date
    s = input1.split('/')
    a = [int(num) for num in s]
    b = sum(a)
    c = [int(i) for i in str(b)]
    d=(sum(c))
    single_digit_dt = str(d)[0]

#     Evaluating car number
    y = [int(num) for num in input2]
    x= sum(y)
    single_digit_platenumber =str(x)[0]

#     Comparing both the numbers
    print(single_digit_dt, single_digit_platenumber)
    if single_digit_dt ==single_digit_platenumber:
        print('Lucky')
    else:
        print('Dare')



lucky_dare()
```